# python mysql.connector, not running sql code

Tags: python, tkinter, mysql-connector

The code is calling a database and producing a table, this function is calling what is selected and running a sql query to swap the exceptions int and move it around in the tables, this works when hard coded into it

```
def selectedRow():
    # Get the currently active tab
    active_tab = tab_control.tab(tab_control.select(), "text")
     
    if active_tab == "Table 1":
        tree = tab1.winfo_children()[0]  # The first child of tab1 should be the Treeview
    elif active_tab == "Table 2":
        tree = tab2.winfo_children()[0]  # The first child of tab2 should be the Treeview
    elif active_tab == "Table 3":
        tree = tab3.winfo_children()[0]  # The first child of tab3 should be the Treeview
    else:
        print("No valid tab selected.")
        return
    # Get the currently selected item in the Treeview
    curItem = tree.focus()
    if not curItem:
        print("No row selected.")
        return

    # Get the data of the selected row and print them to the console
    contents = tree.item(curItem)
    print(contents['values'])
    conn, cursor = connect_to_database()
    exceptions = contents['values'][4]
    filepath = (contents['values'][1],)
    Ex_to_Z = "update tableoffiles set Exceptions = 0 where DataLocation = %s"
    drop_f_ex = "Delete From tableofexceptions where DataLocation = %s"
    Ex_to_O = "update tableoffiles set Exceptions = 1 where DataLocation = %s"
    add_f_ex = "Insert into tableofexceptions select * from tableoffiles where DataLocation = %s"
    drop_f_sum = "Delete From tableofsum where DataLocation = %s"
    add_to_sum = "Insert into tableofsum select * from tableoffiles where DataLocation = %s"
    if exceptions == 1:
        print(filepath)
        cursor.execute(Ex_to_Z, filepath)
        print("setting exept to 0")
        cursor.execute(drop_f_ex, filepath)
        print("add to except")
        cursor.execute(add_to_sum, filepath)
        print("adding to sum")
        refresh_tables()
        print("refreshing tables")

    elif exceptions == 0:
        print(filepath)
        cursor.execute(Ex_to_O, filepath)
        print("setting exept to 1")
        cursor.execute(add_f_ex, filepath)
        print("add to except")
        cursor.execute(drop_f_sum, filepath)
        print("removing from sum")
        refresh_tables()
        print("refreshing tables")

    else:
        print("invalid exception")
        return


# Exception Button: Update the command to call selectedRow()
Exception_button = ttk.Button(window, text="exeptions swap", command=selectedRow)
Exception_button.pack()
```

-- output (exept = 1) --

['HART0001', 'C:/Users/train/7.xls\n', 0, 0, 1] , ('C:/Users/train/7.xls\n',)

setting exept to 0,
add to except,
adding to sum,
refreshing tables

-- output (exept = 0) --

['HART0002', 'C:/Users/Michael/CODE/2.xls', 0, 1, 0] ,
('C:/Users/Michael/CODE/2.xls',) ,
setting exept to 1 ,
add to except ,
removing from sum ,
refreshing tables

At the moment its not changing the database and i am not sure why, any help would be appreciate

Comment: Your example doesn't really show what isn't working.  But unless you have "autocommit" turned on, you need to do `conn.commit()` to have your changes saved immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for insert, update and delete queries you need to execute conn.commit() to commit the change to the database

Comment: yep just figured that out, thank you anyways